# How to use shapekeys to strech a character? How to fix Robort?

Tags: modeling, shape-keys

For what I want, I believe some pictures and descriptions will do best, but I apologize if the story and large number of pictures is annoying, but I don't really have an easy way to describe this otherwise.[image: Picture of Robort]

This is Robort.

Robort is a model that uses shape keys to strech his arms legs and torso.
[image: Picture of Robort streching]

When Robort tries move his arms and legs using an armature like this, or in any way for that matter,

[image: Robort moving with a rig]

and then tries to strech, Robort looks like a monstrousity.
[image: Robort's arms and legs freaking out after stretching]

How do I fix Robort?

Comment: You have to animate stretching by armatures if you use a rig.